# Find the interval in which $a$ lies such that the roots of the equation $(a+1)x^2 - 3ax + 4a$, is greater than 1.

Tags: inequality, roots, quadratics

**Question:**
Find the interval in which $a$ lies such that the roots of the given function, $f(x)$, is greater than 1.
$$f(x) = (a+1)x^2 - 3ax + 4a$$

---

**My Attempt:**

Using the quadratic formula,
$$x = \frac{3a±\sqrt{9(a)^2-16(a)^2-16a}}{2(a+1)}>1$$

First of all, the radicand must be greater than or equal to $0$. From that, we can restrict $a$ to
$$a \in [-\frac{16}{7}, 0]$$

Here, we can make two cases:

1. ***Case I***:
   $a+1>0$

$$±\sqrt{9(a)^2-16(a)^2-16a}>2 - a$$

Now squaring both sides and simplifying it further,

$$-7(a)^2-16a >a^2 + 4 -4a$$
$$2(a)^2+3a+1 <0$$
Hence, $a \in (-1, -\frac{1}{2})$

Intersecting this with the restricted set, we get $$a \in (-1, -\frac{1}{2})$$

2. ***Case II***:
   $a+1 < 0$

Here, we will end up getting,
$$a \in [-\frac{16}{7}, -1)$$

But this is not the required answer. Using [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i7u6ubffiu), it can be clearly seen that for $a\in(-1, -\frac{1}{2})$ there is only one root greater than $1$ and not both.

I suspect that I messed it up while squaring the radical. By squaring, I was trying to find the interval for $a$ where **at least** one root has a value greater than $1$. Right?

How am I supposed to get around it?
Also, is there a better approach for this particular problem?

Comment: If the polynomial has no real roots, the statement "All real roots are greater than 1" is true.

Comment: @PierreCarre *If I may ask*, how did you conclude that?

Comment: It has nothing to do with this problem, it is just logic.  $\forall x \in \emptyset$ (some statement) is always true. This was just to say that the original statement is still true if there are no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

To find the values of $a$ such that real roots of the equation
$$ (a+1)x^2 - 3ax + 4a=0$$
are greater than $1$.

First the discriminant must be positive
$$(3a)^2-16a(a+1)\ge 0\to -\frac{16}{7}\leq a\leq 0\tag{1}$$

Second, if we want both roots greater than $1$, then the sum must be greater than $2$

The sum of the roots is $x_1+x_2=\frac{3a}{a+1}$

$$x_1+x_2>2\to \frac{3a}{a+1}>2\to a<-1\lor a>2\tag{2}$$

Putting together $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have that the roots of the given equation are greater than $1$ if $-\frac{16}{7}\leq a<-1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that solving $\frac{3a}{2(a+1)}<1$ gets you to (-1,2).  In this region the - solution cannot be bigger than 1 since you are subtracting a positive number, so you have to exclude that region